# How to set attribute for a Managed Package lightning component from Another component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I am trying to set the attribute for a Managed Package lightning component which was installed from App Exchange as follows!

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes"
access="global" >
<aura:attribute name="InputRoleName" type="String"/>
<lightning:input  label="Enter the RoleName" name="InputRoleName" value="
{!v.InputRoleName}"/>
<kkltng:Hierarchy apexClassForData="DFSUtils" apexInput="{!v.InputRoleName}"
/>
</aura:component>
```

But it doesn't render the output, all i need to achieve is give the role name as input from the UI and get the role hierarchy for that role!

I dont want to hard code the apexInput="CEO" but want to give the input from UI

Do any one faced this scenario, please do guide me.

Comment: Create an aura:attribute called as "InputRoleName" and then bind it with the lightning:input. This way when some-one enters the value , the two way binding expression will update the value of inputRoleName and the same can be passed to the managed package component.

Comment: i tried that, it doesnt help me

Comment: The binding in lightning:input is not right. it is supposed to be value="{!v.inputRoleName}" and in the managed package component it is supposed to be apexInput="{!v.InputRoleName}" check this out [ https://pastebin.com/6R8bnXnA ]

Comment: I tried this too it doesnt help!